# Civicrm manage organizations

Tags: drupal, civimember

Is it possible to use CiviCRM if I am a federation that wants to manage his associations with his members? How do I manage organizations and households in such a case? Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could flesh this out with much more detail. Xavier's answer about using Organisations and Relationships is good. But without knowing if for example each 'association' should be accessing and managing their own 'members' there is too little here to really provide a substantive answer. Eg there are extensions which mean that each Association can login and access 'only' their members by using the Relationships as Access controls.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your associations as organisation (or create an organisation sub-type "association") and create relationships between your main organisation (the federation) and the associations.

Another way might be to use civimember, if you have to deal with membership fees, but it depends on how you handle your membership structure, and you should probably read the chapter on civimember in our book and experiment